# Remote Desktop vs Logmein - ArcMap vs ArcGIS Pro Performance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, remote-desktop

I use a remote desktop connection through a VPN to work remotely on my computer at the company office, which is connected to a server via ethernet. When I'm using ArcMap via remote desktop, the connection is seamless, there's no noticeable latency. When I use ArcGIS Pro though, the map rendering speed and ArcGIS Pro in general slow down significantly. What's weird is that, when I use ArcGIS Pro via a logmein remote connection, it runs significantly faster vs remote desktop connection. I prefer to work via remote desktop since the resolution is better and it's free. Why would ArcGIS Pro run significantly better through a logmein connection vs remote desktop? And how come ArcMap runs the same regardless of the type of remote connection?

Comment: Sounds like an IT issue, rather than a GIS question?

Comment: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-documents/troubleshooting-performance-issues-in-arcgis-pro/ta-p/1025516 Run the Performance Assessment Tool

Comment: Probably graphics, see [How To: Improve performance of ArcGIS Pro when running over Remote Desktop](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000026552)